# Erro C++: E2034 Cannot convert 'wchar_t *' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++

Ao executar um código C++ ocorrem esses dois problemas:

```
- [BCC32 Error] USerialCommunication.cpp(96): E2034 Cannot convert 'wchar_t *' to 'const char *'
- [BCC32 Error] USerialCommunication.cpp(96): E2342 Type mismatch in parameter '__src' (wanted 'const char *', got 'wchar_t *')
```

Código Fonte:

```
void __fastcall TFSerialPort::EnviarClick(TObject *Sender)
{
        char buff[100];    
        //Converte uma string em array.
        strcpy(buffer, EdCommand->Text.c_str());
}
```

Declaração do EdCommand: `TEdit *EdCommand;`

Declaração do buffer: `char buffer[100];`

Erro ocorre na linha do `strcpy`.

Obs.: O código fonte foi feito no C++ Builder 6 e estou tentando executar no Embarcadero XE2

Comment: Não, a declaração do *buffer* é `char buff[100];` e a chamada do `strcpy` é `buffer`. Possivelmente o erro esteja aí. Qual é o tipo da propriedade `TEdit->Text`. O erro pode estar no `c_ str`.

Comment: Na verdade essa declaração char buff[100] está correta. A variável char buffer[100] está fora deste código. A solução do erro postei abaixo, após um tempo consegui resolver.
Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver, eu converti para AnsiString:

Antes:

```
strcpy(buffer, EdCommand->Text.c_str());
```

Depois:

```
strcpy(buffer, AnsiString(EdCommand->Text).c_str());
```

Comment: Era o que eu estava achando. O tipo do `TEdit::Text` era incompatível com o `c_str()`. Não esquece de aceitar a resposta.

Comment: Pode deixar, em dois dias eu aceito.
Obrigado @bigown